# Highcharts: Remove padding around column chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a Highcharts column chart that I want to be super minimal. Just the bars, no padding, no title, no labels, etc.

I've tried several settings with the api, however I can't seem to get rid of a aproximately 15px padding on the left and right sides of the graph I have built.

My chart settings are as follows:

```
    chart: {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        borderWidth: 0,
        plotBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
        plotShadow: false,
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        margin: 0,
        padding: 0,
        spacing: [0, 0, 0, 0]
    }
```

I thought the `spacing` set to `0` would have fixed the issue however it hasn't.

I have opened a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/kMVB5/16/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply set `minPadding` and `maxPadding` to 0. See: http://jsfiddle.net/kMVB5/26/

```
    xAxis: {
        gridLineColor: 'transparent',
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        lineColor: 'transparent',
        lineWidth: 0,
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tickWidth: 0,
        minPadding: 0,
        maxPadding: 0
    },
```

Comment: For some types of chart need apply this rules for yAxis and it fixes the problem

Answer (score 1):

This will help to remove all left and right empty spaces.

```
plotOptions: {
   series: {
      groupPadding: 0
   }
}
```

Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/column-grouppadding-none/) jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

In the xAxis section, within setOptions, you can add the element:

```
min: data[0]
```

That will set the minimum value in the xAxis to be the first element of your data array.
You can take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hige/kMVB5/23/)

Hope it helps!

EDIT: Actually, that brings some issues. A better approach is to set min to 0 and max to data.length, with the pointInterval set to 1, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hige/kMVB5/25/)

Regards

Answer (score -1):

according to the fiddle you provide, I find a way to erase the 15px padding:
in your css you have a

```
div {
       text-align: center;  
       padding: 15px;  
}
```

in the .graph-wapper class, just delete padding: 15px and it will be fixed.

Be careful this may cause other issues.

Comment: That is used for padding the subtitle divs